# JavaScript の記述を簡潔にしたい

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

よくあるお問い合わせフォームの入力時のバリデーション機能を作っています。
以下のような `_validate` メソッドを作成したのですが
`@$example.parent('dd').prev('dt').addClass('form-error')` が
何度も書かれてしまっているのを、もっと簡潔に記述したいのですが
どうすればいいでしょうか。よろしくお願いします。

```coffeescript
_validate: ->
  errorMessage = ''

  unless @$name.val()
    errorMessage += '<span class="form-alert-text">・お名前を入力してください</span><br>'
    @$name.parent('dd').prev('dt').addClass('form-error')

  unless @$email.val()
    errorMessage += '<span class="form-alert-text">・メールアドレスを入力してください</span><br>'
    @$email.parent('dd').prev('dt').addClass('form-error')
  else
    unless @$email.val().match(/.+@.+\..+/g)
      errorMessage += '<span class="form-alert-text">・メールアドレスが不正な形式です</span><br>'
      @$email.parent('dd').prev('dt').addClass('form-error')

  unless @$email_confirm.val()
    errorMessage += '<span class="form-alert-text">・メールアドレス(確認)を入力してください</span><br>'
    @$email_confirm.parent('dd').prev('dt').addClass('form-error')
  else
    if @$email.val() != @$email_confirm.val()
      errorMessage += '<span class="form-alert-text">・メールアドレスと内容が異なります</span><br>'
      @$email_confirm.parent('dd').prev('dt').addClass('form-error')

  unless @$tel.val()
    errorMessage += '<span class="form-alert-text">・お電話番号を入力してください</span><br>'
    @$tel.parent('dd').prev('dt').addClass('form-error')
  else
    unless @$tel.val().match(/^[0-9-]/)
      errorMessage += '<span class="form-alert-text">・お電話番号が不正な形式です</span><br>'
      @$tel.parent('dd').prev('dt').addClass('form-error')

  errorMessage
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

もっとも単純な方法の1つとして、以下のような関数を定義することを提案します。

```
markAsError = (el) ->
  el.parent('dd').prev('dt').addClass('form-error')
```

この関数 `markAsError` を使うことで、例題のコード `@$example.parent('dd').prev('dt').addClass('form-error')` は次のように単純化されます。

```
markAsError @$example
```

Answer (score 0):

例えばですが（思いつきで入力しているため動作確認はしていません）

```
var nullcheck_keys = {'name'=>'名前','tel'=>'電話番号','email'=>'メールアドレス',....};
```

のように未記入禁止のものをチェックするキーリストを作っておき

```
for(var n in nullcheck_keys){
    $("*[name=" + n +"]").each(function(){
          if($(this).val() == ""){
            error= nullcheck_keys[n] + 'が未記入です';
            $(this).parent....;
          }
    });
}
```

のようにまとめるのも良いのかなとは思いました。